# approximation of a continuous convex function on [a,b]by sum of a linear function and linear combination of functions of the form φ(x) = (x − z)^{+}

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have seen this statement in some book, I also know that a continuous convex function on a compact set can be approximated by $c^\infty$ functions. But I didn't any idea about to prove above statement . Can any one help me to proceed to prove above statement.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: There is no "above statement" - the title is a single noun clause with no verb. Also there's something important missing from the title: In fact any _continuous_ function on $[a,b]$ can be uniformly approximated by those linear combinations; the whole point here is that for a _convex_ function you also get...